# Not getting Proper Sorted Array In Windows Javascript App

Tags: javascript, sorting, windows-store-apps

I am not able to get a proper sorted output in case of a bubble sort algorithm when implemented in the Windows Store App (Javascript) . Below is the source code for Javascript :-

```
function BubbleSort()
{
    var numlist = NumList.value;
    var swap,flag=1,i=0;
    var ar = numlist.split(",");
    Val.value = ar[i];
    while(flag!=0)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < ar.length; j++)
        {
           flag = 0;
            if(ar[j]>ar[j+1])
            {
                swap = ar[j + 1];
                ar[j + 1] = ar[j];
                ar[j] = swap;
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }
    IS.value = ar.toString();
}
```

Input :- "10,4,3,2,1,5,7,6,9"
Output :- "10,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,9"

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 for making the app. Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the default sort algorithm?

Comment: I am trying to make an educational app so this one is also required. Are there default methods to Bubble Sort? o.O

Comment: Yea... [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: I will read about it but could you please see my code and tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this (adjust to your needs):

```
function bubbleSort(v, desc)
{
    var ar = v.split(','), i = v.length;
    while((i-=1,i))
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < ar.length; j++)
        {
            if(desc ? +ar[j]<+ar[j+1] : +ar[j]>+ar[j+1]) //<= numeric comparison
            {
                var swap = ar[j];
                ar[j] = ar[j+1];
                ar[j+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    return ar.join();
}
// usage asc en desc:
bubbleSort('10,4,3,2,1,5,7,6,9');       //=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]
bubbleSort('10,4,3,2,1,5,7,6,9', true); //=> [10,9,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but could you please explain what do you mean by Numeric Comparison which you have done in the If Statement? I used the breakpoints and my code was not even entering the If Code block?

Comment: The `+` sign before `ar[j]` and ar[j+1] converts the value to `Number`, so now it compares two numbers. String comparison would put `'10'` before `'2'`, and return `[1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]`

Comment: Aah thanks for the quick response. It is working now. Marked as Answer. Thanks for the explanation as well ^_^

Comment: Hi @PranavJituri, glad I could help you out. Adjusted the answer to enable descending sort too.